# Can we always write a random variable as conditional expectation plus independent error?

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, conditional-expectation

Consider the random variables $Y,X$. Can we always write
$$
 Y=E(Y|X)+\epsilon\tag 1
$$
with $\epsilon$ **independent** of $X$?

Note: from this answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/509074/can-we-always-write-a-random-variable-as-conditional-expectation-plus-error), we know that we can always write (1) with $E(\epsilon|X)=0$. However, here I am asking if we strengthen the relationship between $\epsilon $ and $X$ to **stochastic independence**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose
$$
Y=X^2+u
$$
where $u|X\sim(0,X^2)$ has conditional heteroskedasticity. Then,
$$
\epsilon=Y-E(Y|X)=X^2+u-E(Y|X)=u,
$$
which has conditional mean zero but is not independent of $X$, as its second moment depends on $X$.

Comment: I'm guessing there is an N missing in $u|X\sim(0,X^2)$

Comment: Not necessarily, the notation is to indicate that $u$ is, conditionally on $X$, distributed with mean 0 and variance $X^2$. It does not have to be a normal distribution.